# fetch data for spinners from REST APi [cascade]

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-mvp

I have in one activity 6 spinners and at the beginnig to 1st one it fetchs data automatically using rest api and retrofit and the for another spinner i need use value which was selected from 1st spinner and fo the 3d spinner i need get selectedItem from second spinner and so on.

i've allready (for fast result) try this in my Activity class:

```
 private fun buildCountryDropDown(order: Int, objectName: Spinner?) {
    try {

        var rooms: Call<Created>? = null

        var selectedObject: String? = null

        val data = jsonApi.getObjects()

        data?.enqueue(object : Callback<Created> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Created>, response: Response<Created>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    listOfDataObjects = response.body()!!.data.toMutableList()
                    println("text==========: " + response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.NameRu)

                    val cAdapter = CreatedAdapter(this@PlanJobActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listOfDataObjects as ArrayList<Data>?)
                    objectName?.adapter = cAdapter
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Created>?, t: Throwable?) {
                t?.printStackTrace()
            }
        })

        objectName?.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                selectedObject = listOfDataObjects[position].tid

                rooms = jsonApi.getRooms(selectedObject!!)

                showToast("$selectedObject was selected!")
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
        }
        //=============================================ROOMS============================

        rooms?.enqueue(object : Callback<Created> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Created>, response: Response<Created>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    listOfRooms = response.body()!!.data.toMutableList()
                    println("text==========: " + response.body()?.data?.get(0)?.NameRu)

                    val cAdapter = CreatedAdapter(this@PlanJobActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listOfRooms as ArrayList<Data>?)
                    vnp?.adapter = cAdapter
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Created>?, t: Throwable?) {
                t?.printStackTrace()
            }
        })

        vnp?.onItemSelectedListener = object : OnItemSelectedListener {

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                selectedObject = listOfRooms[position].tid

                showToast("$selectedObject was selected!")
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {}
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

I know it is very very bad idea to write logic in activity but i just try, but not works. it fetch data only for first spinner but other spinners stay empty. For fetching data from rest api i'm using a retrofit and how can you see i get data from responce by `enqueue` method witch allows me to fetch data async. I understand that i need remaster my project to MVP but i dont know how to start?

Comment: before converting to MVP, just try to make it work for all spinner. Generally on one spinner selection it should have some method like on spinner selected, where you will get the data for second spinner